# how long have I got to wait until the googlebot scan my website once again?

Tags: googlebot, web-crawler

In the statistics of my website I saw that the google crawler have scanned my website once, unfortunately my website is under construction and some informations that have been changed earlier became obsolete then. I tried to inform myself on the googlebot scan frequency but I'm not sure to find right informations about it. On google help page there's a link allowing us to request google to perform a new scan of our website, anyway it seems this link is targeting webmasters who suspect troubles in their indexation (not my case). I was just wondering how long do I need to wait until the googlebot crawl my page again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[The answer](http://www.google.com/support/webmasters/bin/answer.py?answer=34439)
is that there is no answer, unfortunately.

I have found that it can take anywhere from 48 hours to a week to get reindexed.